# How do I create categories in a ggplot legend for a barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a barplot showing the FLFP of those born before and after 1975.

I have used the following code to create a barplot

```
library(ggplot2)

cohort_colors09 <- c("11-15" = "#FF7256", "16-20" = "#FF7256", "21-25" = "#FF7256",
                     "26-30" = "#FF7256", "31-35" = "#FF7256", "36-40" = "#EE3B3B", "41-45" = "#EE3B3B",
                     "46-50" = "#EE3B3B", "51-55" = "#EE3B3B", "56-60" = "#EE3B3B", "61-65" = "#EE3B3B")

ggplot(dplyr::filter(agecohort_sum,  year == 2009 & !(age_cohort == "6-10" | age_cohort == "0-5" | age_cohort == "66+")), aes(x = as.factor(age_cohort), y = flfp, fill = age_cohort)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.7) + 
  labs(x = "Age cohort",
       y = "FLFP rate in 2009") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(color='black'),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cohort_colors09, labels = c("Born after 1975" = "#FF7256", "Born before 1975" = "#EE3B3B"))
```

The output looks like this

[image]

However, I would like the legend to indicate that the bars associated with the colour "#FF7256" to say "Born after 1975" and the colour "EE3B3B" to say "Born before 1975". Please help me do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new variable in your dataframe which bins before and after 1975 and run your `aes()` from that variable rather than the true age ranges.

Something like this

```
dat <- data.frame(age_cohort = c("11-15", "16-20", "21-25", "26-30", "31-35", "36-40", "41-45" ,
                                           "46-50", "51-55", "56-60", "61-65"), 
                            flfp = 1:11)

dat_groups <- dat %>%
  mutate(group = case_when(age_cohort %in% c("11-15", "16-20", "21-25", "26-30", "31-35") ~ "After 1975",
                           TRUE ~ "Before 1975"))

ggplot(dat_groups, aes(x = as.factor(age_cohort), y = flfp, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.7) + 
  labs(x = "Age cohort",
       y = "FLFP rate in 2009") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(color='black'),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FF7256", "#EE3B3B"), labels = c("Born after 1975", "Born before 1975"))
```

[image]